# How to parse a string containing a sequence of rectangles data?

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++03

I should parse a string containing some data in the following format:

- the image named in the string is associated with zero, one or more rectangles;
- the coordinates of the rectangle are enclosed in parentheses and are formed by four integers separated by commas;
- each rectangle is separated from the next one by a comma;
- the string ends with a semicolon.

Example of the string:

```
"image.png": (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax), (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
```

I would like retrieve the following informations:

- a `string` containing the filename of the image, for example `image.png`;
- a `vector<Rect>` containing the sequence of the rectangles.

Rect is the struct defined below:

```
struct Rect
{
    int xmin;
    int ymin;
    int xmax;
    int ymax;
}
```

How to deal with the problem in a simple way, without using external libraries?

Comment: Regular expressions are your friends. Implementing this particular case yourself is cumbersome, and why would you? Is this another homework/assignment?

Comment: @Haroogan: How to use the regular expressions?

Comment: See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex). **NOTE:** Your standard library has to be C++11 compliant.

Comment: @Haroogan: How to check if my standard library is C++11 compliant?

Comment: Which compiler do you use (name and version, please)?

Comment: @Haroogan: g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3

Comment: Unfortunately, even the latest GCC 4.8.0 does not fully support regular expressions. You have to use [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) library. If that's not an option for you, then you'd have to implement this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with the problem in a simple way, you can use a automation implements with switch case.You need only 10 states at all.The states are list below:
INIT,FILENAME,COLON,PARENTHSIS,XMIN,YMIN,XMAX,YMAX,COMMA,ACCEPT.
The init `state` is `INIT`.
So the switch case statement is:

```
ch = getNextChar();
switch( state )
{
    case INIT:
        if( ch == '\"' )
          state = FILENAME;
        break;
    case FILENAME:
        if( ch != '\"' )
          filename.append(ch);
        else
          state = COLON;
        break;
    case COLON:
    // more cases;
    // ...
    default:
}
```

like this, you can easily parse this string.

Comment: You forgot `WHITESPACE` state.

Answer (score 0):

Try clang.
As :

```
clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ yourfile.cpp
```

Clang 3.3 supports regexes. Runs on Linux if needed.